# if i enter any random words it is not displaying "NO book found"

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

i am using google books api in my android book Listing app all works fine but i am not able to use setEmptyView() for the listView when their is no book found all it says is there is some error in AsyncTask doInBackground 
below is my code and logcat

Books.java //details of books

```
package com.example.ashis.booklisting;

/**
 * Created by ashis on 10/14/2016.
 */
public class Books {
    private String bookTitle;
    private String bookAuthor;
    private String bookPublisher;
    private String mUrl;

    public Books(String bookTitle, String bookAuthor, String bookPublisher, String Url) {
        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
        this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
        this.bookPublisher = bookPublisher;
        mUrl=Url;
    }

    public String getmUrl() {
        return mUrl;
    }

    public String getBookTitle() {
        return bookTitle;
    }

    public String getBookAuthor() {
        return bookAuthor;
    }

    public String getBookPublisher() {
        return bookPublisher;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml // where listView is declared

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ashis.booklisting.MainActivity">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_search // a button and editText for title/publisher/author to search

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ashis.booklisting.Search_Activity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_search"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="159dp"
        android:minWidth="300dp"
        android:hint="title/author/publisher"
        android:minLines="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="search"
        android:id="@+id/button_search"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_search"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

custom_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView_title"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView_author" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView_publisher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

customAdapter.java

```
package com.example.ashis.booklisting;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ashis on 10/14/2016.
 */
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Books> {
    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Books> booksArrayList) {
        super(context,0,booksArrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rootView = convertView;
        if (rootView== null){
            rootView= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,parent,false);
        }
        final Books currentBook = getItem(position);
        String title = currentBook.getBookTitle();
        TextView titleText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
        titleText.setText(title);

        String author = currentBook.getBookAuthor();
        TextView authorText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_author);
        authorText.setText(author);

        String publisher = currentBook.getBookPublisher();
        TextView publisherText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_publisher);
        publisherText.setText(publisher);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ashis.booklisting;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      private TextView emptyText;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        emptyText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String qry = intent.getStringExtra("searchQuery");
        Log.i("qry",qry);
        if (qry.contains(" ")){
            qry.replace(" ","+");
        }
        String JSON_RESPONSE = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+qry;
        Log.i("JSON",JSON_RESPONSE);
       ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,new ArrayList<Books>());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        BookAsyncTask task = new BookAsyncTask();
        task.execute(JSON_RESPONSE);
        listView.setEmptyView(emptyText);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Books books = adapter.getItem(position);
                Uri booksUri = Uri.parse(books.getmUrl());
                Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,booksUri);
                startActivity(webIntent);

            }
        });
    }

    private class BookAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<Books>>{

        @Override
        protected List<Books> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            if (urls.length<1 || urls[0]==null){
                return null;
            }
            List<Books> result = QueryUtils.fetchBookData(urls[0]);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Books> books) {
            adapter.clear();
            if (books!=null && !books.isEmpty()){
                adapter.addAll(books);
            }
            emptyText.setText("No books Found");
        }
    }
}
```

QueryUtils.java

```
package com.example.ashis.booklisting;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ashis on 10/14/2016.
 */
public class QueryUtils {

    public QueryUtils() {
    }

    public static List<Books> fetchBookData(String requestUrl)
    {
        URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);

        String jsonResponse = makeHTTP(url);

        List<Books> books = extractFromJson(jsonResponse);

        return books;
    }

    private static URL createUrl(String requestUrl) {

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url=new URL(requestUrl);
            try {
                URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
                url = uri.toURL();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return url;
    }

    public static List<Books> extractFromJson(String jsonResponse){
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(jsonResponse)){
            return null;
        }
        final List<Books> booksArray = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            JSONArray itemsArray = root.optJSONArray("items");
            Log.i("length",String.valueOf(itemsArray.length()));

            for (int i=0;i<itemsArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject singleItem = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject volumeInfo = singleItem.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
                Log.i("title_book",title);

                String author = volumeInfo.getString("authors");
                Log.i("author_book",author);
                String publisher = volumeInfo.getString("publisher");
                Log.i("publisher_book",publisher);
                String website = volumeInfo.getString("previewLink");
                Log.i("url",website);

                booksArray.add(new Books(title,author,publisher,website));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return booksArray;
    }

    public static String makeHTTP(URL url){
        String jsonResponse = "";
        if (url == null){
            return jsonResponse;
        }
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.connect();
            int serverCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.i("server_Code",String.valueOf(serverCode));
            if (serverCode == 200) {
                inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromInputStream(inputStream);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection!=null){
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream!=null){
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    private static String readFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream!= null) {
            InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
            String line = bufferReader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = bufferReader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString() ;
    }
}
```

SearchActivity.java

```
package com.example.ashis.booklisting;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Search_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_);
        final EditText editText_search  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_search);


        Button buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_search);
        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String searchText = editText_search.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("searchQuery",searchText);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ashis.booklisting">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Search_Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #9
                                                                             Process: com.example.ashis.booklisting, PID: 5084
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.ashis.booklisting.QueryUtils.extractFromJson(QueryUtils.java:69)
                                                                                 at com.example.ashis.booklisting.QueryUtils.fetchBookData(QueryUtils.java:38)
                                                                                 at com.example.ashis.booklisting.MainActivity$BookAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:58)
                                                                                 at com.example.ashis.booklisting.MainActivity$BookAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:51)
                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: The empty view isn't the problem according to the error... Anyways, I'd look into using the SearchView class. There's not much reason to have an Activity only for searching

Answer (score 0):

Following line in QueryUtils is causing crash :

```
Log.i("length",String.valueOf(itemsArray.length()));
```

This also indicates that ***root*** object might not contain ***items*** array.
Debug your app and checkout the outcome at following line too:

```
JSONArray itemsArray = root.optJSONArray("items");
```

To remove exception, add a check whether itemsArray is null or not, and return value for function accordingly.

Comment: if itemsArray is null should i return null ?

Comment: **Yes**, you should return null. As returning null would evaluate your conditions written in **onPostRequest** of **AsyncTask** inside **MainActivity**. If empty view isn't visible yet then try to set visibility of empty view (Visible) and your listview (Invisibe) and vice versa when results are not null. I tried the api you're using in chrome extension (Postman). Try that too to see what's inside the response to verify code.Hope it helps. Please accept answer if it works for you.